# Shared Transition Animation Glitch

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, shared-element-transition

**What I Have**

I have set the permission correctly.

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>        
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>

<!-- specify shared element transitions -->
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
```

And this is my transition file,

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeImageTransform/>
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

Now, in my master activity, I gave a GridView with image thumbnails.

```
View photo = (View) list.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.fileThumb);
                    photo.setTransitionName("photo" + position);
                    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), Pair.create(photo, photo.getTransitionName()));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Config.GALLERY_EXTRA, position);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

In my Detail activity,

I have a ViewPager with a fragments. In the onCreate() of the fragment, I did this.

```
final PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
                    relativeLayout.addView(photoView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
photoView.setTransitionName("position"+pos);
```

The animation seems to work on the correct items, but not smoothly. There seems to be a glitch in the animation. However, the exit transition is somewhat smooth. But still not perfect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the PhotoView library by Chris Banes? If so, it's not yout fault but a bug in the library: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/243

Comment: There are two possible workarounds I've found, but neither of them worked for me :/
1. Use an usual ImageView instead of Photoview and then set the PhotoViewAttacher onto the ImageView once the transition is finished. I couldn't figute out how to to correctly set up the listener though.
2. Display a second ImageView behind the PhotoView and make it invisible afterwards. Didn't work either, because somehow setVisibility(View.GONE) wouldn't work. 
Feel free to try out these workarounds yourself, maybe you'll get it to work.

Comment: Thanks I will see if I can find any other workaround.